# Question related to amicable numbers not divisible by 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In a paper by W. Borho and S. Battiato, the authors show that there do exist odd amicable numbers which are not divisible by 3. For their examples they found a common factor:

$a=5^{4}\cdot 7^{3}\cdot11^{2}\cdot 13^{2} \cdot 17^{2} \cdot 19 \cdot 61^{2} \cdot 97 \cdot 307$.

What I am trying to understand is if every odd amicable pair that is not divisible by $3$ (either member) must have this common factor $a$ or if this was just one example of such an $a$?

Link to paper provided below in comment, sorry for poor link

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=2NqsXOHEJsvH-gTxjKEI&q=amicable+numbers+not+divisible+by+3&btnK=Google+Search&oq=amicable+numbers+not+divisible+by+3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.6213.11057..11238...0.0..0.100.2667.34j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.pgQJOwUeUJg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper presented was a counterexample of a conjecture on amicable numbers. The belief was that every pair of odd amicable numbers $(x,y)$ followed the rule $3 \mid x$ and $3 \mid y$. They used the common factor $a= 5^4⋅7^3⋅11^2⋅13^2⋅17^2⋅19⋅61^2⋅97⋅307$ to construct their counterexamples. However, this common factor need not divide all odd amicable pairs. The authors meant that $a$ divided all of their pairs used to disprove the conjecture.

The above can be seen clearly by considering two unsolved problems in mathematics:

$(1)$ **Are there any pairs of amicable numbers with one odd and one even positive integer?**

$(2)$ **Are there any pairs of relatively prime amicable numbers?**

If we knew that $a$ divided all pairs of amicable numbers where $3$ didn't, then we would know that all pairs of odd amicable numbers cannot be relatively prime. The only possibility for the same is if there exist an odd - even pair of amicable numbers, which are relatively prime. Then, we would get the following relation:

$$(1)=\mathbf{False} \implies (2)=\mathbf{False}$$
$$(2)=\mathbf{True} \implies (1)=\mathbf{True}$$

The paper by W. Borho and S. Battiato was written in the year $\mathrm1988$. Here is a line from the paper - "On Relatively Prime Amicable Numbers" by Paul Pollack, written in the year $\mathrm2000$ -

> In fact, if $N$ and $M$ are assumed to have opposite parity, then
>   $10^{67}$ can be replaced with $10^{121}$.

Here, the author is talking about the lower bounds for relatively prime pairs of amicable numbers $(N,M)$. This line proves that we were unaware of a relation such as the above, between the two conjectures. This is only possible if the authors of the $\mathrm1988$ paper meant that $a$ divided all of their pairs only.

It need not be that $a$ does not divide all pairs which are not divisible by $3$, but this would be a highly unlikely scenario.

**Citations:**

*Paper by Paul Pollock* : [On Relatively Prime Amicable Pairs](http://pollack.uga.edu/borhoexplicit3.pdf)

*Paper by W. Borho and S. Battiato* : [Are There Odd Amicable Numbers Not Divisible by Three?](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-50-182/S0025-5718-1988-0929559-5/S0025-5718-1988-0929559-5.pdf)

Comment: this is excellent and 100% what I was asking. In the middle where you talk about implications of odd even pair and one implying the other is false or true would you be able to elaborate on exactly what is implied ?

Comment: The only possibility for the same is if there exist an odd - even pair of amicable numbers, which are relatively prime. Then, we would get the following relation:

Comment: If all odd-odd pairs have the common factor of $3$ or $a$, then if $(N,M)$ are relatively prime amicable numbers, then they are an odd-even pair, since an even-even pair has a common factor of $2$.

Comment: So, if the set of pairs of relatively prime amicable numbers is $A$, and the set of pairs of odd-even pairs is $B$, then $A \subseteq B$. Thus, $B=\emptyset \implies A=\emptyset$. Moreover, if $A \neq \emptyset$, then $B \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: This explains that True and False relation, if that was what you were asking...